# ejabberd 2.01's module "mod_eventful" could not be loaded

Tags: php, erlang, ejabberd

We are using **Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS** on which we have installed **ejabbered 2.1** but given plugin [mod_eventful](https://github.com/theozaurus/mod_eventful) is not working.

We have checked error log under `var/www/ejabbered/ejabberd.log` and found below error log

```
{'module could not be loaded',
[{http,request,
[post,
{"http://192.168.1.60/messages",
[{"Authorization",
"Basic SFRUUCBCQVNJQyBVU0VSTkFNRTpIVFRQIEJBU0lDIFBBU1NXT1JE"}],
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"from=kandhal%40192.168.1.60/15310114851488363705601144&to=hitesh%40192.168.1.60&type=chat&subject=&body=%7B%22isdownload%22:false%2C%22issent%22:false%2C%22fromuserid%22:%22kandhal%40192.168.1.60%22%2C%22ptopid%22:%22%22%2C%22messageid%22:%221488363577548%22%2C%22message_time%22:%221488363577911%22%2C%22mediathumb%22:%22%22%2C%22is_read%22:false%2C%22isseen%22:false%2C%22fromprofilepic%22:%22%22%2C%22isread%22:false%2C%22messagesource%22:%22VGhlIG9ubHkgcHJvYmxlbSBJIGhhZCB3YXM%3D%22%2C%22messagetype%22:%22text%22%2C%22fromusername%22:%22Kandhal%20AB%22%7D&thread="},
[],
[{sync,false},{stream,self}]],
[]},
{mod_eventful,handle_call,3,
[{file,"src/web/mod_eventful.erl"},{line,188}]},
{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [this post](https://github.com/theozaurus/mod_eventful/issues/5)?

The error message says that `http:request/4` could not be loaded.
Because  `http:request/4` was removed in R15B.

Maybe you see warning message like below,

> src/web/mod_eventful.erl:139: Warning: call to http:request/4 will fail, since it was removed in R15B; **use httpc:request/4**

Unfortunately, this module seems like to support **ejabberd 2.1.x**, and the creator of this module, supports no longer.

Comment: seems like http:request/4 would be available in ( as per plugin requirement )  erlang version R14B04 and should support the module mod_eventful? Or should we downgrade the version of erlang from R16B04 to R14B04 ? or Is there any plugin available which does use for same purpose ?

Comment: I can't recommend your question, because I've been not test the version `R14B04`. However, there are two options. First why don't you make your own module? You already have the source file, `mod_eventful.erl`. Second, why don't you test R14B04 + ejabberd 2.1.x on your other test machine?(Although, the version is too old.)

Comment: We have tried to downgrade erlang version from R16B04 to R14B04 still we are not able to invoke the message hook while user A sends a message to user B using mod_evenful module. Our debug log looks like https://ibb.co/d4Jw5a